# Gunicorn, Heroku, and pushState/HTML5 History API support

Tags: backbone.js, heroku, marionette, gunicorn, pushstate

If I run [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) can I support [pushState and the HTML History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) on my [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)-hosted app?

I would like to not have hashes in my [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)/[Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) app.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, gunicorn will have nothing to do with this. To use pushState, your server must return a valid page for any URL your client-side application generates.

For example, if your Marionette app has a "/articles/5/comments" URL, the server MUST respond with valid content when it receives that URL.

That said, your server can systematically return the same content (e.g. via a catch all route) that simply contains your complete Marionette app. Then, the client side app will take over, aprsing the route, and loading the data.

Comment: I guess it is that simple David.  I expected something more complicated because StackMob doesn't support pushState (yet) with their HTML5 Hosting sevice.  I guess they must have an Apache server that hasn't incorporated these changes: http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/.